# GC420t Zebra Printer Calibration Issue

Tags: zebra-printers

I alternately use 2 different sizes of label in my work (Barcode and Price Tag), I had a TLP2844 Zebra Printer and when changing the labels it calibrated automaticly to the rigth size of label( was fine), now i have a GC420t Zebra Printer and i cant calibrate it (i can calibrate it to only 1 size), if a change the label, it prints like having the old size (Dont calibrate automaticly), is this cant be done anymore? I apreciate you could help me.

PD: I still have the TLP2844 Working fine, the GC420t is a brand new printer for another branch.

Answer (score 0):

from: https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SO8284

3. Media Feed Power up action

The first time you load media you should run the 2 flash calibration procedure described in step 4. The Media Feed setting then determines how the media is handled when the printer is powered on or when the printhead is opened and closed.

The printer defaults to feed one label after power up or when the printhead is opened and closed. This is intended to position an already calibrated label to its resting position to be ready for printing. This can be altered using the Media Feed setting to one of the following:

Calibrate 
Feed (Default)
Length
No Motion
Short Cal

If you wish to alter the default setting you can create a file using the ^MF command to change the values. If you don't want to alter the printer defaults you can use the two flash calibration each time you change label lengths See Calibration below.

Setting the Media Feed (Power Up Action) on the printer requires sending the ^MF command to alter the Power Up Head Open value. Sending a file using the ZebraDesigner Tools feature. Read More>>

^MF (Media Feed command) Read More>>

Example of a ZPL Media Feed Command to Measure the Label Length when the head is closed.

^XA^MFN,L^XZ (Power Up = no motion, Head Close = Measure the length)
^XA^JUS^XZ (Saves the value)

For recommendations on these selections Read More>>